Continuity in the topological sense, and singlets as open/closed sets
First of all I apologise if this question will sound stupid. I'm approaching to the study of topological spaces and real analysis in a deeper way, that is trying to fill holes and doubts and this one has came in my mind.
I'll start with this: consider the set $A = \{\frac{1}{n+1}: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. In my definition, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now $A$ is a set which I can write as a union of singlets, and each singlet is a closed set. So far so good, I know why they are closed and so on.
Now consider the function $f: [10, 11] \cup \{14\} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = x^2$. The domain of $f$ is closed, since it's a finite union between a compact set and a singlet. Though, I just found out, reading over here and else, that actually $\{14\}$ is not a closed set: it's open!!
This is due to the topological definition of continuity I have read, that is: $f$ is continuous if the pre image of any open set of $\mathbb{R}$ is open.
For my case let's take $(196-\delta, 196+\delta)$ where for example $\delta = 1/3$. This is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, but the preimage which is $f^{-1}(196-\delta, 196+\delta) = 14$ that is $\{14\}$ which is apparently not open, for what I know of singlets. But this would mean $f$ is not continuous at $x = 14$.
Can someone please help me in understanding where I am wrong? I may suppose that the reason of what I did not understand may lie into "what topology" I am using, but here other doubts arise.
Taking back the set $A$, this is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so what topology am I using? The discrete one? After all every singlet of $A$ is closed.
But again, when studying the continuity of $f$ at $x = 14$, what topology am I using? Would the result change? I don't even know if it makes sense to use the discrete topology here...
What if I had $f: [10, 11] \cup \{14\} \to \mathbb{Q}$, how would things change?
Thank you for your time...

${14}$ is indeed open (and closed) in $X=[10, 11] \cup {14}$ since it equals $X\cap (13,15)=X\cap [13,15]$, but it is not open but closed in $\mathbb R$. You need to review the definition of subspace topology.

What's wrong is that you didn't note that the actual space that you're are considering is $[10, 11]\cup\{14\}$ as a subspace of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
This is the space: ($[10, 11]\cup\{14\}$, $\tau$), with the topology $\tau = \{U \cap ([10, 11]\cup\{14\}) \mid U$ is an open subset in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}\}$.
Notice that $\{14\}$ is clopen in this subspace.
Why is $\{14\}$ open in this subspace? Because $]13, 15[$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and $]13, 15[ \cap ([10, 11]\cup\{14\}) = \{14\}$. So, we have that $\{14\} \in \tau$. So, the preimage of $]196-\frac{1}{3}, 196+\frac{1}{3}[$, which is correct that it is $\{14\}$, is open.
Notes:
The set $A$ of your second paragraph, despite you haven't explicitly mentioned if it is closed or not. I clarify that it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider $\epsilon > 0$ and note that $]-\epsilon, \epsilon[$ has non-empty intersection with $A$. Therefore, every neighborhood of $0$ has non-empty intersection with $A$, and as $0$ isn't in $A$, $A$ isn't closed.
The finite union of closed sets is closed, but as you can see, this doesn't hold for unions that aren't finite. A space where countable unions of closed sets are closed is called P-space, and a space where arbitrary unions of closed sets are closed is called Alexandrov. (Evidently, each Alexandrov space is a P-space, but there are P-spaces that aren't Alexandrov (see: cocountable topology on $\mathbb{R}$)).
If we have a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ between spaces, where $X$ is discrete, then $f$ is continuous (since every subset of $X$ is open in it's discrete topology). Just saying to remind that, the continuity in this case is trivial. However, the space that you where considering for the domain of your function wasn't discrete.
Singletons being closed doesn't make the topology discrete. The topology is discrete if, and only if, each singleton is open. Spaces where every singleton is closed are called $T_1$. Evidently, a discrete space is $T_1$, but there are $T_1$ spaces that aren't discrete, like the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$. If you read more about $T_1$ spaces, you will realize or read that, since every singleton is closed, the topology refines the cofinite topology on such set.
Finally, there exists $x \in [10, 11]\cup\{14\}$ such that $f : [10, 11]\cup\{14\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}; f(x) = x^2$ isn't defined.

Thank you for this, I will read it carefully. May I ask you questions here in the comments, if there is something I don't get, or I have doubts on (related to my question/your answer of course)?

You're welcome, and sure!

Ok, I have two questions: $(1)$: the set $A$ I mentioned at the beginning was not closed (I forgot to say), but I don't understand how the topology you mentioned later is related to $A$. When you defined $\tau$...
$(2)$: According to the topological definition of continuity, how can I show that the pre-image of an open set is open here? What I wrote above, how can I formalize it? I mean I tried with $f^{-1}(196-\epsilon, 196+\epsilon) = {14}$. Maybe this is riht, and ${14}$ is also open, relating to what you said about $\tau$, but then question $(1)$ is the main one eventually. Thanks!

I have edited my answer answering to these new questions. When it comes to your first, I'm sorry that my notation had confused you, when I defined the subspace topology, I used $A$ to denote open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

Thank you so much, now it's all clear!

You're welcome! I'm glad that now it is clear for you.

Sorry just a very last question, perhaps I am rust in set theory: what if instead of $(13, 15)$ I chose $(0, 1)$?

Then, the resulting open set is: $]0, 1[ \cap ([10, 11] \cup {14}) = \emptyset$. The reason why I considered $]13, 15[$ before is because I wanted to prove that ${14}$ is open in the subspace, i.e. that there exists an open set of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology such that, the intersection of this set ($]13, 15[$) with our subspace ($[10, 11] \cup {14}$) is equal to ${14}$.

Ahh, you're right. I lost from the view that the goal was to show ${14}$ was open. Perfect, thank you again!!

No problem, and you're welcome!
